# Python: Parse string of bracketed list items into list of strings

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string containing several items listed in the following notation:

```
myString = '[A][B][C]'
```

And I would like to parse that to a python list of several strings:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I know this can be solved with:

```
myString = myString.lstrip('[')
myString = myString.rstrip(']')
myList = myString.split('][')
```

I'd just like to know if there is an even more pythonic way of doing it.
Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653143/10983441 where the most elegant way in the end was to use pyparsing with nestedExpr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a regular pattern that describes what you want to do with a string, using a regular expression (regex) is usually a good idea. In addition to using `re.split`, as shown in [another answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254701/98493) by [@python_user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/233379/python-user), you can also use `re.findall`, which has the advantage that you don't have to manually deal with the opening and closing delimiters:

```
import re
re.findall('\[(.)\]', '[A][B][C]')
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

This finds all single characters (`.`), which are surrounded by square parenthesis (`\[...\]`) and selects only the character itself (`(.)`).

If you want to allow more than one character between the parenthesis, you need to use a [non-greedy version of `*`, the `*?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766377/4042267):

```
re.findall('\[(.*)\]', '[][a][a2][+%]')
# ['][a][a2][+%']

re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', '[][a][a2][+%]')
# ['', 'a', 'a2', '+%']
```

---

Regarding your code itself, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case` instead of `pascalCase` for variables and functions.

You could also chain your calls together without sacrificing too much readability (even gaining some, arguably):

```
my_list = my_string.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split('][')
```

Comment: seeing this answer makes me want to up my regex game :D

Comment: normal strip can be used instead of rstrip and lstrip: `my_list = my_string.strip("][").split("][")`, but string slicing could be used instead: `my_list = my_string[1:-1].split("][")`

Answer (score 4):

A Regex based solution

```
>>> my_string_one
'[A][B][C]'
>>> re.split(r"\[([A-Z])\]", my_string_one)[1:-1:2]
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> my_string_two
'[A][B][C][D][E]'
>>> re.split(r"\[([A-Z])\]", my_string_two)[1:-1:2]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

You can use `re.split` with the expression `\[([A-Z])\` having a capture group for the uppercase letters. This is under the assumption that your strings always follow this pattern otherwise you may not get what you expect.